# Need to start domain on Glassfish, get error: There are no domains in "directory"

Tags: unix, netbeans, directory, glassfish

I do have "domains1" dir but when I do "asadmin change-admin-password", I get an error saying "There are no domains in ~/glassfish3/glassfish/domains".
But I do have a "domains1" dir and it has all the files necessary to run the application online.
I'm trying to do this through Terminal while ssh-ing in. Here's a screenshot:
https://app.box.com/glassfish3

==UPDATE==
Was able to change the password, and was able to 'asadmin stop-domain', but now cannot do 'asadmin start-domain', getting the same error, There are no domain in ....

Comment: It might be worth seeing the output of 'ls -la ~/glassfish3/glassfish/domains'

Comment: I have this: drwxr-xr-x 11 andtsy pgxxxxxxxx xxxx Jul 22 22:05 domain1

Comment: It would be nice if you could answer your question describing how you solved your initial problem, I'm having it too.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, a problem in the glassfish installer prevented it from creating the domain correctly.

I used the **create-domain** command to create it manually;

something like:

```
PS C:\glassfish3\bin> .\asadmin create-domain domain1
Enter admin user name [Enter to accept default "admin" / no password]>
Using default port 4848 for Admin.
Using default port 8080 for HTTP Instance.
Using default port 7676 for JMS.
Using default port 3700 for IIOP.
Using default port 8181 for HTTP_SSL.
Using default port 3820 for IIOP_SSL.
Using default port 3920 for IIOP_MUTUALAUTH.
Using default port 8686 for JMX_ADMIN.
Using default port 6666 for OSGI_SHELL.
Using default port 9009 for JAVA_DEBUGGER.
Distinguished Name of the self-signed X.509 Server Certificate is:
...
Domain domain1 created.
Domain domain1 admin port is 4848.
...
Command create-domain executed successfully.
PS C:\glassfish3\bin>
```